# Security vs File Size

Tags: python, linux, encryption, computer-science, filesize

I am really interested in computer security and I have started building my own encryption software, the only problem is that the encrypted output file is much larger than the original file size sometimes it is a 1:3 ratio.

so the question is, at what point is the file size increase ratio too large for the encryption to be worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size should not increase beyond any block padding, usually 8 to 16 bytes.

But building your own encryption software may seem neat but it is not going to be secure. The current symmetric standard, AES, went through a multi-year competition, review and selection process.

A good starting point is to learn the current methods and previous methods leading up to them, there is a large amount of information available on the web to study. There are also free on-line cryptography courses on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org), [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com) and others. Then learn how to use the current methods.

Finally: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.